# What are the changes in Michelson in Dalphanet?

Tags: michelson

Dalphanet introduces quite a few new primitives and types.

What are these primitives and types?
What are their typing rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Agora post contains a summary of Michelson changes for this 007 protocol proposal: https://forum.tezosagora.org/t/state-of-the-languages/1559/7.

I think that the protocol currently being used in Dalphanet contains all the mentioned features except tickets (that are being finalized).